# How to disable BOM in RAD studio SOAP request (using WSDL importer) when compiling Multi-Device app for Android

Tags: android, web-services, delphi, soap, byte-order-mark

I am using RAD Studio 11 to build Multi-Device Application in Delphi to act as SOAP Client against OpenEdge WEB Services and produce needed types and classes via WSDL Importer.
Win32 and Win64 built applications works without any problems and everything goes fine. The problem appears in Android app. Using TCPMon in proxy mode to intercept SOAP requests and responses I found that Android app adds 3 bytes BOM(0xEF,0xBB,0xBF) in the beginning of SOAP envelope:

**BOM**`<?xml version="1.0"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV ...`

This is caused error in server side parsing with message:

```
<errorMessage>
Error in SOAP Envelope: parsing error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. (10913)
</errorMessage>
```

The question is how to disable BOM in requests provided by THTTPRIO type when compiling for Android.

> I can not test the application in iOS and macOS (have no MAC PC).

Here is IInvokable interface implementation from WSDL importer and couple lines added by me:

```
function GetLBLObj(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): LBLObj;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://server:8080/wsa/wsa1/wsdl?targetURI=urn:service:LBL';
  defURL  = 'http://server:8080/wsa/wsa1';
  defSvc  = 'LBLService';
  defPrt  = 'LBLObj';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
    RIO.HTTPWebNode.UseUTF8InHeader := True;
    RIO.HTTPWebNode.Proxy := 'http://tcpmon:8081';
  try
    Result := (RIO as LBLObj);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thank You in advance!